# ICC compiler - error: parallel loop condition does not test loop control variable

Tags: c, openmp, icc, intel-mic

I am trying to parallelize a "for loop" of my C/OpenMP code, after offload call on Intel MIC (Xeon Phi) card. I am using "#pragma omp parallel for" and it compiles good when I use an integer variable as "loop control variable". On my code I am using a float array as "loop control variable" and then I get the error "parallel loop condition does not test loop control variable".

Code with no error:

```
#define MAX_DIMENSIONS  10

unsigned long long  i,y=0;

#pragma offload target(mic) in(i,y)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        /* code here */  
}
```

Code with error:

```
#define MAX_DIMENSIONS  10

float   x[MAX_DIMENSIONS];
unsigned long long  i,y=0;

#pragma offload target(mic) in(x[MAX_DIMENSIONS],i,y)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(x[0]=0.000000; x[0]<10.000000; x[0]+=1.000000)
        /* code here */
}
```

Is there any way to keep that float array notation in "for loop" in order to succeed the parallelization using OpenMP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenMP parallel for with floating-point range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418908/openmp-parallel-for-with-floating-point-range)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the working sharing manually like this

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    float a = 0., b = 10.;
    float step = 1.;
    int N = (b-a)/step;
    int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    float t0 = (ithread+0)*N/nthreads + a;
    float t1 = (ithread+1)*N/nthreads + a;
    for(float x=t0; x<t1; x += step) {
      //code
    }
}
```

This would be equivalent to

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for(float x=a; x<b; x += step)
```

if the `omp for` construct supported floating point iterators. For other schedules such as dynamic you have to implement them differently. Note that it's possible the parallel code and then sequential code don't give the same result e.g. if `(b-a)/step` has a fractional part (but `(10.-0)/1. = 10.` is okay). Therefore it's probably best to change your code to use integer iterators to be safe.

Comment: Is doing N times of float increment (`float x; for(;i<N;i++)x+=some_float_step`) always equal to (`int N = (b-a)/step;`)? What about last iteration in case of non exact representation of step and high N?

Comment: @osgx, I think there are several cases where it's not equivalent actually. One of the most important is that `sum(x)` over n terms is not in general the same as `x*n` (i.e. repeated addition is not equivalent to multiplication) for floating point arithmetic. For integers this is not a problem but for floats it is. I just wanted to give an answer to show that it's possible to do work sharing with floating point iterators with OpenMP if one really really wants to do this.

Comment: I really wanted to work with floating point iterators with OpenMP and that solution works perfect on my code. It was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @wasilis, be aware that using floating point accumulators/iterators means that the number of iterations executed may depend on the number of threads since floating point arithmetic is not associative.

Answer (score 4):

OpenMP requires loop variable to be of integer type:

http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf#page=68

> The syntax of the loop construct is as follows:
>
> ```
> #pragma omp for  ...
>  for-loops
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Specifically, all associated for-loops **must have canonical loop form** (see Section 2.6 on page 53).
>
> 3 The iteration count for each associated loop is computed before entry to the outermost loop. If execution of any associated loop changes any of the values used to compute any of the iteration counts, then the behavior is unspecified.
>
> 6 The integer type (or kind, for Fortran) used to compute the iteration count for the collapsed loop is  implementation defined.

You can't use variables of floating type in openmp loop construction. Your first loop has `i` integer which is correct and second has `float` typed variable which is incorrect. Canonical loop form is defined in "2.6 Canonical Loop Form" - http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf#page=62 as

> ```
> for (init-expr; test-expr; incr-expr) structured-block
> ...
> var - One of the following:
> * A variable of a signed or unsigned integer type.
> * For C++, a variable of a random access iterator type.
> * For C, a variable of a pointer type
>
> incr-expr One of the following:
>  ...
> * var += incr
>
>  incr A loop invariant integer expression
> ```

and your second loop has not canonical form and can't be paralleled.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(x[0]=0.000000; x[0]<10.000000; x[0]+=1.000000)
```

It will be hard to compiler to get loop iteration count in advance with floating point values of var and incr: some decimal constants can't be represented exactly in floating point format (for example, 0.2 in floating point is 0f3FC999999999999A; and 0.1 + 0.2 is 0.30000000000000004 in many languages, check https://0.30000000000000004.com/).

You can try array of integers or `long`s or `long long`s:

```
#define MAX_DIMENSIONS  10

long long  x[MAX_DIMENSIONS];
unsigned int i,y=0;

#pragma offload target(mic) in(x[MAX_DIMENSIONS],i,y)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(x[0]=0; x[0] < 10; x[0] += 1)
        /* code here */
}
```

Or you can try to estimate correct loop count for floating point range before loop and then use integer iterators in parallel loop as var and incr (be sure to do correct rounding).

Comment: Actually the code includes multiple nested "for loops" in that way, and works fine in another edition of the code for parallelization in CUDA or in serial execution. So the only way to use correctly the OpenMP is to change the structure of my "for loops". Thank you for your answer!

Comment: wasilis, check also http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf#page=62 "2.6 Canonical Loop Form", this is definition of loop form required after `#pragma omp for`, and only allowed are: integer type, random access iterator type (C++), and pointer type (and increment of ptrdiff_t type)