# OpenMP error invalid controlling predicate

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I have written the following code and trying to parallelize it using openmp. but i am unbale to compile the program and end up with error **invalid controlling predicate error**

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
for( ; i+o<N*C && i < C*n; i++ )
       buf[i] = (a[i]-b[i])*(a[i]-b[i]);
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312679/why-is-the-operator-not-allowed-with-openmp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rewrite the loop like this and it should work:

```
int maxII = min( N*C-o, C*n);
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
for ( int ii=i; ii<maxII; ii++ )
   buf[ii] = (a[ii]-b[ii])*(a[ii]-b[ii]);
```

OpenMP for loops have to follow a "Canonical Loop Form" as described in the [standard chapter 2.6](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf#G4.1507160)

---

EDIT: **"Could you please explain me what was wrong with my code?"**

Well, the loop form you used isn't compliant with OpenMP's "Canonical Loop Form" which basically (I over-simply here, sorry) asks that:

- the loop index is clearly defined;
- the lower bound of the loop is given in the initialisation part;
- the test is one of the following operators: `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=`; and
- the increment is clear.

I simply rewrote your loop to abide to these simple rules. It was easy enough, as it is in most cases.

Comment: thanks @Gilles , its working. Could you please explain me what was wrong with my code?