# Iterate over unordered_map in parallel for, without auxiliary container for keys

Tags: c++, openmp

Intention is to iterate over an `std::unordered_map` in parallel with `OpenMP` shown as follows:

```
  std::unordered_map<int, int> ht;     
  // add key-value pair in the unordered_map
  #pragma omp taskloop
  for (auto i = ht.begin(); i != ht.end(); ++i) {
      std::cout << i->first << "\t" << i->second << std::endl;
  }
```

However, `OpenMP` for parallel for doesn't allows `!=` for good reasons as explained in this existing [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312679/why-is-the-operator-not-allowed-with-openmp?noredirect=1&lq=1).

One way is to keep an auxiliary data structure like 'std::vector' to keep track of all the keys and do as follows:

```
std::vector<int> keys_ht;
// add keys in keys_ht
 #pragma omp taskloop
 for (int i = 0; i < keys_ht.size(); ++i) {
     std::cout << keys_ht[i] << "\t" << ht[keys_ht[i]] << std::endl;
 }
```

The above strategy would require extra storage and extra hashing for each element is `std::unordered_map`.

Is their any way to avoid creation of this auxiliary data structure?

Comment: Can you use a range-based for loop? `for (auto const& item : ht)`

Comment: Are you required to use openMP, for an assignment perhaps, or can you use STL `thread` or `async` instead?

Comment: @CoryKramer does `openmp` supports range-based for loop?

Comment: @Jiveadson its not for an assignment. I didn't wanted to use `thread` as the rest of the code is optimized for `openmp`